# Change Woocommerce media query breakpoint to load woocommerce-smallscreen.css at max-width: 767px instead of 768px

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Woocommerce load `woocommerce-smallscreen.css` at max-width 768px. How can I change it to 767px? I use this css file so I want it to be loaded but also change somehow this media query breakpoint.

I searched for this media query in woocommerce css files but I didn't find this phrase which I see in chrome devtools: `media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)"`

Comment: Maybe in layout.css or woocommerce-layout.css? Which Theme you are using?

Comment: I'm using my custom theme, but with Woocommerce 2.6.4 (WP version is 4.6.1). I've been searching in files you mentioned but with no result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this Woocommerce filter in functions.php.

```
// Change Woocommerce css breaktpoint from max width: 768px to 767px  
add_filter('woocommerce_style_smallscreen_breakpoint','woo_custom_breakpoint');

function woo_custom_breakpoint($px) {
  $px = '767px';
  return $px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide the answer to the same quesiton for Storefront (change the mobile/desktop breakpoint)? Thanks

Comment: Man you saved my day, I'm amazed, thanks!