# Storefront: switch to mobile layout for 768px-wide screens

Tags: css, woocommerce, storefront

I am developping a child theme of Woocommerce Storefront.

On a tablet (portrait, 768px wide), I would like the "mobile" layout (burger menu, etc) to be displayed, instead of the the desktop layout (main-menu, etc).

I used the following css media queries:
`@media (max-width: 768px)` for mobile 
`@media (min-width: 769px)` for desktop
in my css file.

But all the media queries of storefront seem to activated desktop layout for `@media (min-width: 768px)`.

How can I change this breakpoint?

**EDIT 1:** I tried to edit the file wp-content/themes/storefront/assets/sass/utils/_variables.scss to

```
$desktop:           769px;
$handheld:          768px;
```

but it doesn't change the layout.

**EDIT 2:** I tried this in the functions.php

```
// Change Woocommerce css breaktpoint from max width: 768px to 767px  
add_filter('woocommerce_style_smallscreen_breakpoint','woo_custom_breakpoint');
function woo_custom_breakpoint($px) {
  $px = '769px';
  return $px;
}
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: u mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612275/change-woocommerce-media-query-breakpoint-to-load-woocommerce-smallscreen-css-at

Comment: @Hash it's something like this yes! But the code in this link doesn't work for me. For a width of 768px I still see the desktop menu, whereas I need the mobile menu. Can you help me further ?

Comment: @Hash any other idea?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, maybe you know of any fix for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I changed the breakpoint value in /storefront/assets/sass/utils/_variables.scss and recompile all Storefront files (including sass files) using the grunt file in storefront.
Just run `$ grunt`.

Comment: Yes indeed, but do you suggest a better solution ?

Comment: I'm hitting the same problem, after updating the theme !! Did anyone find a good solution ?